# In a generic method, how to pass in classes based on conditions and capture return value

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method that accepts `T` like this and returns IEnumerable.  Based on some condition, I have to pass in a different class.  Then I iterate the results.

```
public IEnumerable<T> DoWorkGetResult<T>(string param)
    yield return (T)typeof(T).GetMethod("CreateRow").Invoke(null, new object[] { someOtherParam });

//etc...

object resultRows;

if (param == "some condition")
    resultRows = _data.DoWorkGetResult<TClass1>(param);
else
    resultRows = _data.DoWorkGetResult<TClass2>(param);

foreach (var dataRow in resultRows) //error, object hasno public def for GetEnumerator
{

}
```

**The problem is this:**  I don't know how to initialize the return value.  I used `object`, which is fine.  But how do I then loop it?

Comment: `IEnumerable resultRows;` instead of `object` should do it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fd1meoN.png <-- Nope.

Comment: Add `using System.Collections;` at the top of your code file.

Comment: Oh, wow.. d'oh.  Thanks.

Comment: you can't create an instance of `IEnumerable`, it's an Interface but a generic collection so you return an instance of a collection that actually implements that interface like a `List`

Comment: @mijail He's not creating an instance of `IEnumerable`, hes casting the collection returned from the `CreateRow` which returns something that is compatible with `IEnumerable<T>` which inherits `IEnumerable`, so he can do it the way I suggested (and the accepted answer says).

Comment: @RonBeyer it's true missed that part xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Ron Beyer mentioned, resultRows can't be iterated through if it's just an object.  change it from `object resultRows` to `IEnumerable<T> resultRows` and the foreach should compile.

Answer (score 0):

The return type could be any generic collection mostly a interface `IEnumerable`, `IList`, etc. Not necessary a `IEnumerable<T>` just a simple `IEnumerable` or `IList`, on the other side you will know what class are you working on and cast when the method returns the result.

I use `IList` in this cases give you more functionality.

```
var typeClass = typeof(T); // Or maybe Type.GetType("myNamespace.myClass")
var listInstance = (System.Collections.IList)typeof(List<>)
                                .MakeGenericType(typeClass)
                                .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
                                .Invoke(null);
// Add Some instance from T
var objectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeClass); // Create a Instance
listInstance.Add(objectInstance);
```

Just another idea. Have fun :)